# Why it is ok to pass an uninitialized variable address to pointer paramter of a function

Tags: c, pointers, nullpointerexception

let's say we have a C function like this,

```c
void assign(int* refs)
{
 *refs = 123;
}
```

and call it in two ways

1.

```c
int a;
assign(&a); // a is assigned a value.
```

2. 

```c
int* a;
assign(a);// runtime error
```

I know that assign value to pointer that points to null is not ok since there is not correspond memory being allocated.
But
**[1]** why passing address of uninitialized variable works well?
**[2]** What does `&a` means when `a` hasn't been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a problem to *read* an uninitialized variable.  Taking its address is fine since a variable's address is fixed for its lifetime.

In your first example you have an uninitialized variable of type `int`.  You take its address (which is valid as above) and pass it to a function which subsequently dereferences that address to write the value of `a`.

In the second example, you have an uninitialized variable of type `int *`, but then you pass its *value* to the function.  This is not valid because the value of the variable is **indeterminate**.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So it is ok to write value to an uninitialized variable, but assign value to null pointer will first require to dereference the pointer to retrieve the value, which is an undefined behavior.

Comment: @branson The uninitialized pointer isn't even necessarily NULL.  It could have any random value.

Answer (score 1):

The value is uninitialized, but the memory is allocated.Pointer points to memory, not to a value.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I'm a little confused, what do you mean "the memory is allocated"